# Analog method for measuring distinct phase shifts

Tags: rf, signal-processing, phase-shift

I have a signal that undergoes distinct 90 degree phase shifts but has an unpredictable frequency over a predefined range (anywhere from DC to 300MHz). From my limited knowledge on PFDs, they can only measure a phase difference between a reference frequency and another of the same frequency. Is there an analog way to detect those 90 degree phase shifts (like the ones that occur in BPSK modulation) and/or a method to measure the phase difference between two waves of different frequencies? Phase and frequency are linked hand-in-hand so I don't think the latter is possible.
I'd like to avoid having to use ADCs and digital signal processing if possible.

Comment: Personal Flotation Device?

Comment: I'm sure there might be but we know nothing about your signals especially the unpredictable stuff you mentioned. To measure phase you MUST have a reference signal.

Comment: In RF parlance, a **mixer** gives you phase difference between two waves of different frequencies. Most mixers include some output components of other frequencies, which can usually be attenuated with frequency-selective filters. You'd have to decide if a filter could separate *undesired* mixer output frequencies from *desired* ones.

Comment: You could try fast comparators, XOR'ed, driving a constant current source with a capacitor as load. You'll get variable ramps with amplitude directly proportional to the delays between the zero-crossings -- this should not depend on frequency. At the end of the ramp, use an analog sample & hold. The working frequency range is problematic, though: what cap (or current) should there be for 300 Hz vs 300 MHz? Also, if the frequencies differ by a significant amount, you'll get garbage differences.

Comment: What's the source of this signal?  How clean is it, eg, what else do you get along with it?  How instantaneous is the transition, and is it shaped?   What information are you actually trying to recover here?   Most likely your actual application problem has a typical solution, but the way you've stated the problem gives no point of leverage to determine a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From my limited knowledge on PFDs, they can only measure a phase difference between a reference frequency and another of the same frequency.

Phase is a difference in time between two things. Like voltage it is measured between two things. A phase detector is therefore a device that takes two signals and gives you the phase between them.  It will always take two inputs for the same reason a voltmeter takes two inputs.

> Is there an analog way to detect those 90 degree phase shifts (like the ones that occur in BPSK modulation) and/or a method to measure the phase difference between two waves of different frequencies?

If two signals have different frequency, then the phase difference between them increases at 2PI times the difference in frequency between them per second.  That isn't what you're looking for, it'll just be a constantly increasing signal with occasional extremely tiny changes in slope when the phase of one signal changes.

Usually you have a reference clock or something similar that you compare against to see if phase has changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a reference at the same frequency, let's say an unpredictable VCO driving two paths, one direct, the other through a 90 degree phase shift device, then the two signals could be compared in a simple phase detector. Each change of 90 degrees would result in a change of output.

If you only have one signal, then an unpredictable frequency means an unpredictable rate of change of phase. You want to detect a sudden 90 degree phase shift. You had better hope that there's some way of distinguishing the unpredictable wander from the 90 degree shifts, perhaps the frequency varies slowly enough for a PLL to track it? If so, monitor the error signal at the phase detector of the PLL. Most of the time it will wander up and down a bit to track the slowly varying frequency. From time to time, it will jump by 90 degrees. Choose the loop bandwidth to be fast enough to track the unpredictable variations in frequency with little phase error at the PSD.

Answer (score 0):

Given you want to compare timing, you can try this.

- divide each signal by 2, using a FlipFlop; this guarantees exactly 50% duty cycle (well, within the limits of cycle_cycle timing jitter)
- connect both FFs to an EXOR gate.

The EXOR produces a frequency_doubling (which we don't care about), but also does a edge_timing comparison which we exploit.

- Low_pass_filter the EXOR output.
- monitor the DC output of the LPF

At 90 degrees, you should have VDD/2 DC output.

Realize not all EXORs will do this accurately, because of internal logic paths.